# JTA transaction timeout exception - weblogic 10.X

Tags: timeout, weblogic, transactions, jta

I changed the JTA transaction timeout from admin console and set to 300, even after changing it fails saying JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout) with a:

```
weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction timed out after 181 seconds`
```

To make sure whether my changes (timeout value 300) got reflected for that domain or not I checked under domain `config.xml` it got reflected with 300.

My question is, is there any other place also do I need to update the transaction timeout value and do I need to restart the server ?

Full stack trace after the exception from server below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction
 timed out after 180 seconds
BEA1-160A800A149091F72E5E
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:709)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:359)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy103.saveRegistryData(Unknown Source)
    at gov.cms.pqri.arch.submission.registry.bean.RegDataAccessManager.persistRegistry(RegDataAccessManager.java:54)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction timed out after 180 seconds
BEA1-160A800A149091F72E5E
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:1818)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:333)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:227)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1028)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: According to the weblogic console, you don't need to restart the server. Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: after changing the stuck Thread Max time to 300 under servers -> configuration -> tuning (tab) from admin console it is getting updated and working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after changing the stuck Thread Max time to 300 under servers -> configuration -> tuning (tab) from admin console it is getting updated and working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have also came across this issue and have resolved the same, since this is related to JTA transaction so we need to increase the timeout of JTA as well along with the time out for stuck max thread. Please click on JTA from the weblogic console home and increase the JTA timeout from `30(by default) to 300`.

Answer (score 2):

We met same issue on Weblogic 12.1.2 [JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout)] after all investigation we found the root cause of the problem.In my opinion it occurs due to huge dataset processing transactional and near the end of the process If an exception is thrown, JTA is rolling back data as expected.But it does not give the details of the error.In our case ,it mostly cause because of the database integrity (e.g we try to insert data a column with smaller size than data.)

In summary,it will be the best way to investigate db logs instead of increasing  stuck Thread Max time.Thread max time can be a solution,but not a proper solution for real enterprise systems.

Also this issue discussed on [another stackover link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428434/weblogic-error-caused-by-weblogic-transaction-internal-appsetrollbackonlyexcep) and [hibernate jira issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9888)

And solution suggested:

> This is a default behaviour of Weblogic JTA realization. To obtain
>   root exception you should set system property
>   weblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason to true.
>
> One of the solution is add this line into
>   /bin/setDomainEnv.cmd:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my JTA timeouts increased by adding jta.properties file into config folder of my app with lines:

```
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=600000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=600000
```