# Weblogic Error: Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, weblogic

I am porting an application from Jboss 7as to Weblogic 12c.

So far, I am able to run the application and create new records in the database.

However, I get the below error only when trying to update existing records;

```
Error committing transaction:
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Error committing transaction: 
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwTransactionRolledbackLocal(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:231)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwEJBException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:134)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:362)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:205)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:46)
    ...
Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction
```

The error happens when I call `javax.persistence.EntityManager.merge(Object)` inside a Stateless EJB whose transactions are container managed.

My initial thoughts were that the container is calling `javax.transaction.UserTransaction.setRollbackOnly()` somewhere, so I changed the EJB's transaction management to BMT and managed the transaction myself. The same error occurred.

I suspect that my Datasource or persistence.xml have a problem.

Below is my persistence.xml's properties

```
<persistence version="2.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myunitname" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>myDS</jta-data-source> 
 <properties>
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
 <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
 <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
 <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="1"/>
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform"/>
 </properties>
```

Please assist.

Comment: Same here, seems to be a known issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8181

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it out.

Answer (score 11):

This is a default behaviour of Weblogic JTA realization. To obtain root exception you should set system property `weblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason` to `true`.

One of the solution is add this line into `<domain_home>/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd`:

`set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason=true`

or linux equivalent into `<domain_home>/bin/setDomainEnv.sh`

Comment: Noted.. I will give this a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot , It's really save my time .

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the root cause you can surround your code with Try/Catch and inspect the Exception like this:

```
try {
    javax.persistence.EntityManager.merge(Object);
}catch(Exception ex) {
    Throwable rootCause = ex;
    while (rootCause.getCause() != null) {
        rootCause = rootCause.getCause();
    }
    
    System.out.println(rootCause.toString())
    // LOGGER.debug(rootCause.toString());
}
```