# No persistence error details seen using JPA 2.1

Tags: hibernate, transactions, weblogic12c, jpa-2.1

I have forced the error of sending a string higher than the maximum allowed in the table column, the trace when performing persist in the DB shows me a generic error, and I have not managed to know the exact error generated. I tried to get the cause without getting a trace similar to SQLExeception.

**Cosiderations:**

- JPA 2.1 + WL12.2.1 + Oracle DB XE 11g.
- I know what I can validate the length before doing persist.
- Using SP the error trace shown is the one I expect (SQLException).

**Code**

```
package pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.service;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import pe.com.claro.common.property.Constantes;
import pe.com.claro.common.resource.util.HeaderRequestBean;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.repository.AlumnoRepository;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.util.AlumnoModel;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.util.DistritoModel;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.message.request.InsertarAlumnoRequest;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.message.response.InsertarAlumnoResponse;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.persistencia.entity.Alumno;
import pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.persistencia.entity.Distrito;

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class AlumnoService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlumnoService.class);

    @EJB
    private AlumnoRepository alumnoRepository;

    @Resource
    private EJBContext context;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public InsertarAlumnoResponse insertarAlumno(InsertarAlumnoRequest request, HeaderRequestBean headerRequest) {

        InsertarAlumnoResponse response = new InsertarAlumnoResponse();
        UserTransaction utx = context.getUserTransaction();

        try {
            LOG.info("Insertar alumno mediante JPA:");

            utx.begin();

            LOG.info("[Actividad 1 - Registrar Venta]");

            Distrito distrito = DistritoModel.setDatosDistrito(request);
            Alumno alumno = AlumnoModel.setDatosAlumno(request, distrito);

            String requestPrintHeader = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                    .writeValueAsString(headerRequest);
            LOG.info("Datos de Entrada Header:\n {}", requestPrintHeader);
            String requestPrintBody = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(alumno);
            LOG.info("Datos de Entrada Body: \n {}", requestPrintBody);

            alumnoRepository.persist(alumno);

            utx.commit();
            LOG.info("Registro realizado con exito.");

            response.setMensajeError(Constantes.MENSAJEOK);
            response.setCodigoRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_CODIGO_IDF0);
            response.setMensajeRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_MENSAJE_IDF0);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            **LOG.info("Ocurrio un error de BD: \n {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);**

            if(utx != null){
                try {
                    LOG.info("[Actividad 2 - Rollback]");
                    utx.rollback();
                    LOG.info("Rollback finalizado con exito");

                } catch (IllegalStateException | SecurityException | SystemException e) {
                    LOG.info("Error realizando Rollback: \n {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                    response.setMensajeError(e.getMessage());
                    response.setCodigoRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_CODIGO_IDT3);
                    response.setMensajeRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_MENSAJE_IDT3);
                }
            }
            if (ex.getCause() != null && ex.getCause().toString().indexOf(Constantes.CONSTANTE_NO_JNDI) != -1) {
                response.setMensajeError(ex.getMessage());
                response.setCodigoRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_MENSAJE_IDT2);
                response.setMensajeRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_MENSAJE_IDT2);

            } else {
                response.setMensajeError(ex.getMessage());
                response.setCodigoRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_CODIGO_IDT3);
                response.setMensajeRespuesta(Constantes.INSERTAR_ALUMNO_MENSAJE_IDT3);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

**Log**

> SERVER: AdminServer [ INFO] [13-08-2017 16:57:58.867] (AlumnoService.java:80)          - Ocurrio un error de BD: 
>    setRollbackOnly called on transaction
>   weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:2022)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:363)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:254)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:387)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.usertransactioncheck.BaseUserTransactionProxy.commit(BaseUserTransactionProxy.java:25)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.usertransactioncheck.SLSBUserTransactionProxy.commit(SLSBUserTransactionProxy.java:9)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.service.AlumnoService.insertarAlumno(AlumnoService.java:72)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.service.AlumnoService_4y64rk_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.domain.service.AlumnoService_4y64rk_NoIntfViewImpl.insertarAlumno(Unknown Source)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.resource.AlumnoResource.insertarAlumno(AlumnoResource.java:111)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.resource.AlumnoResource_f2da90_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.resource.AlumnoResource_f2da90_NoIntfViewImpl.insertarAlumno(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>       at pe.com.claro.demo.alumno.resource.util.HTML5CorsFilter.doFilter(HTML5CorsFilter.java:27)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>       at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>       at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
>       at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
>       at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
>       at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>       at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
>       at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>       at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>       at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>       at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>   Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:621)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionManagerImpl.java:420)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionManagerImpl.java:413)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1509)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.handlePersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1585)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1693)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(EntityManagerImpl.java:235)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3139)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:316)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.callBeforeCompletion(ServerSCInfo.java:1499)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.doBeforeCompletion(ServerSCInfo.java:1468)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.callBeforeCompletions(ServerSCInfo.java:1434)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.startPrePrepareAndChain(ServerSCInfo.java:128)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.localPrePrepareAndChain(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1554)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalPrePrepare(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2368)
>       at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:287)
>       ... 74 more

Answer (score 0):

Would not be sufficient to change the log level to TRACE/FINEST on the JPA implementation to get more information from processing?

Or for debugging purposes to set tracing on Oracle jdbc driver?
(download driver with debugging capabilities - like ojdbc6_g.jar, use -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true and set the logging category `'oracle.jdbc.driver'` to TRACE)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm

Comment: I'm using the WebLogic 12.2.1 application server and I connect through data source.

Comment: That's what I was talking about But I could not understand what you need to achieve. Is it fine to get more info about an error right? Change the logging level to show you more info. Or create the datasource in was that is using this specific jdbc drive rand pass the -D parameter for weblogic before it starts.

Comment: sorry if I have not been very clear when explaining my problem, the problem is not that if you write me or not in the log file, the problem is that the catch error does not indicate an error "ORA-XXXX "But a very general error, however when using SP the log shown if you give me precise details of the error.
For this case I have sent a string of length greater than that allowed in the column of the table.

Comment: ok, I see. I'm sorry, I was responding on totally different question :/

Comment: I think the original exception could be eaten at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.handlePersistenceException - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.1/hibernate-entitymanager/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/spi/AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java#L1589

Comment: could you see the exception with message 'Unable to mark for rollback on PersistenceException:' in your log?

Comment: the complete trace of the log is published in the question, I have not been able to get more information from the log, I thought it could be within the cause of the cause ... of the exception, but only one cause is the exception generated.

Comment: hm, interesting... Just again I'm not sure understanding well. The question contains only the exception trace but I was talking about whole server log if there could be the message somewhere (probably before this exception) in the log.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behaviour of Weblogic JTA realization. To obtain root exception you should set system property weblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason to true.

One of the solution is add this line into <domain_home>/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason=true
```

or linux equivalent into <domain_home>/bin/setDomainEnv.sh

[Weblogic Error: Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428434/weblogic-error-caused-by-weblogic-transaction-internal-appsetrollbackonlyexcep)