# weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I have the bellow case, Where I call doSomeTask() of BeanA but if doSomeTask() fails I want to persist ErrorInfo into another table as well calling the saveError(ErrorInfo) of BeanA. Both of them has @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW).

```
class BeanA {

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doSomeTask(){

       if(someCondition){
          throw new SomeException();
       }

       // do task  
    } 

    @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveError(ErrorInfo error) {
          // save error info if doSomeTask fails
    }
}

 class BeanB {

     BeanA beanA;

     void performTask(){
           try{
              beanA.doSomeTask();     
            }catch(Exception e){
              ErrorInfo error = getErrorInfo(e)
              beanA.saveError(error);  
            }
     }   
 }
```

But when doSomeTask() throws Exception saveError() doesn't work and throws Exception

```
Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this error? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a spanning transaction?

Comment: No, performTask() is not transactional, as much as I know.

Comment: Is your BeanA injected by container? I.e. do you have @EJB annotation on "BeanA beanA;" ?

Comment: @user3714601 yes, its injected properly. 
The above is just an example of the scenario I am facing not the exact code.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for the late answer. The problem was resolved.

The actual error was hidden. In my case, the actual error was just a JSR 303 validation error of ErrorInfo instance while persisting. Had to add

`Dweblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason=true`

on `<domain_home>/bin/setDomainEnv.sh` to find out the actual error and fix it. Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38584687/1563286

Answer (score 1):

I have debugged the similar issue not so long ago. In my case the issue was the following:

- there was a top level transaction open when the `REQUIRES_NEW` method is called
- After exception in nested transaction commit of the top level one failed to commit as "marked as rollback only"

It turned out that through a new transaction is started the connection holder is shared on `TransactionManager` level. When exception is thrown inside nested transaction the connection itself is marked as rollback only. So later this is causing the issue.

I was able to resolve the issue by using the savepoints (available since JDBC 3.0). Usually savepoints are disabled in many environments/ORM by default and using them requires additional configuration.

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will surely look into it.