# Exception handling in EJB with Container Managed Transaction using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, ejb, weblogic12c

I have a problem with catching hibernate exceptions inside EJB with container-managed transaction.

```
package com.somepackage;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyBusiness {
   @EJB
   Archiver archiver;

   public void doSomething(Request request) {
       try {
             Response response = new Response();
             archiver.archive(request, response);
       } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class Archiver {
    @EJB
    private RequestManager requestManager;
    @EJB
    private ResponseManager responseManager;

    public void archive(Request request, Response response) {
        try {
            requestManager.create(request);
            responseManager.create(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ResponseManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "datasource")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void create(Response response) {
        try {
            entityManager.persist(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class RequestManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "datasource")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void create(Request request) {
        try {
            entityManager.persist(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the thing is i cannot catch exceptions like ConstraintViolationException and etc. although i can see the error logs in Weblogic console, my catch only reports transaction rollback and nothing more.

//console Log

May 13, 2019 10:58:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
May 13, 2019 10:58:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."REQUEST"."REF_EXCEPTION_ID")

////log Ends Here

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428434/weblogic-error-caused-by-weblogic-transaction-internal-appsetrollbackonlyexcep)

i just need to set this inside my Weblogic Env.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.transaction.allowOverrideSetRollbackReason=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should catch ConstraintViolationException like this:

```
try {
    // your logic...
} catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
    Throwable t = e.getCause();
    while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    if (t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        // Handle ConstraintViolationException...
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see I already tried to catch exceptions inside my Archiver, RequestManager and ResponseManager but control never reaches there. the only place that i can see exception is inside MyBusiness Class which it's type is TransactionRolledbackLocalException and unfortunately it's cause is an instance of weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException.